# removing index.php from subfolder using htaccess not working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to remove index.php from my subfolder url. so if anyone access www.mysite.com/sub-folder/index.php i want the url to redirect to www.mysite.com/sub-folder/.
I've added the following htaccess file in sub-folder, but its not working.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub-folder/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /sub-folder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this .htaccess in `/subfolder/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub-folder/

# remove index.php from URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ $1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: its work, but if file does not exist in folder its not return to 404 page instead return index page content i mean for example 'page.php' file is not in 'subfolder' but if i call 'www.mysite.com/subfolder/page.php' this file is getting the content of index.php from 'subfolder'

Comment: 404 won't be returned because you're sending every non-file and non-directory to `index.php`

Comment: Hi, how to make `mysite.com/8to10differentsubfolders/index.php OR mysite.com/8to10differentsubfolders/` to `mysite.com/8to10differentsubfolders.php` through htaccess? Note: all subfolder have `index.php` file only inside it.

Comment: Please post a new question.